# can't locate node in package

Tags: ros, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI everybody, I am having problems in building a large project. I'am trying to add some modularity to my .launch file. I built my launch file as follows

```
<launch>
 <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
   <arg name="world_name" value="$(find vtol_gazebo)/worlds/vtol.world"/>
  </include>


    <include file="$(find heterogeneous)/config/heterogeneous.xml"/>

</launch>
```

with the file included being

```
<launch>

  <node pkg="heterogeneous" name="het" type="heterogeneous">  
  </node>

</launch>
```

the node in the heterogeneous package is (successfully) built with the following CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(heterogeneous)
                                                                                                                                      
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
)

set(ARMADILLO_INCLUDE /usr/local/include/)
set(ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES /usr/lib/libarmadillo.so)

include_directories(include/${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(heterogeneous src/Heterogeneous.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )

catkin_package(
  DEPENDS
    roscpp
)
```

The file si successfully compiled and the executable added to the project workspace. In fact, if I prompt from the catkin workspace

```
find -executable -name heterogeneous -type f
```

I obtain

```
./build/heterogeneous/heterogeneous
```

However when I launch the .launch file I get

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [heterogeneous/heterogeneous]: can't locate node [heterogeneous] in package [heterogeneous]
```

I really cannot figure out what the problem is. I am using ros hydro
Any ideas?
Thanks
Andrea

EDIT: actually I cannot run the node with

```
rosrun heterogeneous heterogeneous
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145801/can%27t-locate-node-in-package/) by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2014-03-28

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xinwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/36542/xinwf/) on 2018-07-18**:
This doesn't work any more. I use the ros version kinetic, farid's method is useful for me.

**Comment by [antoineniotna](https://answers.ros.org/users/34023/antoineniotna/) on 2019-05-13**:
I just had the same problem, but for me the problem was in the launch file. I created my node with catkin command, and then personalized the cmake and the launch file, but I did a mistake by switching name_node to name.
I know it is a very specific mistake but maybe it will help the next guy!

True:

```
<node name="$(arg node_name)" pkg="hil" type="hil_node" clear_params="true" output="screen">
```

False:

```
<node name="$(arg node_name)" pkg="hil" type="hil" clear_params="true" output="screen">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the problem, I had to add the line

```
catkin_package()
```

to the CMakeLists.txt file

---

Originally posted by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) with karma: 385 on 2014-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [graouve](https://answers.ros.org/users/20227/graouve/) on 2014-09-18**:
This solved my problem too. Thanks for the find.

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2016-05-30**:
But your CMakeLists.txt file above already contains a catkin_package statement.
Did simply adding that line solve your problem?

**Comment by [Mago Nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5206/mago-nick/) on 2016-05-31**:
It's a two years old post, so I cannot be 100% sure. But yes, that solved the issue. Now that I know more about that I can tell you that the error is I put the catkin_package statement at the end. After declaring the executable. It has to be done before the find package statements (imho)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For python nodes, check the permissions on the script. If it's not marked as executable, then you will get this same cryptic error message.

---

Originally posted by [crunchex](https://answers.ros.org/users/25178/crunchex/) with karma: 376 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 30

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2016-10-13**:
This answer solves it for me. This one gets me every time, and somehow I forget later on down the road.

**Comment by [chingchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29943/chingchi/) on 2017-04-05**:
Thanks for this info. This is why i cannot locate node in package.

**Comment by [transhumanism](https://answers.ros.org/users/34625/transhumanism/) on 2018-04-12**:
yeah, I got the same problem. Thanks for your answer!

**Comment by [AlexG](https://answers.ros.org/users/37783/alexg/) on 2018-09-27**:
2 years later and also ran into this issue... They really could setup an additional check for permissions before throwing an error about not finding the file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-27**:
ROS is an open-source project. It depends on people like you to find issues and solve them. If all we do is complain nothing will change. You have the power to fix this for all future users, including yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those fellows who are still getting the same error:

Go to your catkin workspace:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
```

and bash file needs to be added to devel folder:

```
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) with karma: 165 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xinwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/36542/xinwf/) on 2018-07-18**:
This works for me, my ros version is kinetic.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue in my case it was no execution permision for python file.
To make file executable please go your package/src directory and type

```
chmod +x your_file.py
```

You may want to check first if files have execution permision by cmd

```
ls -la
```

If file is executable it should have x permision in list like:

```
rwxrwxrwx
```

If file is not executable ls -la will display it without x:

```
rx-rw-r--
```

---

Originally posted by [greatonion](https://answers.ros.org/users/37373/greatonion/) with karma: 41 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-04-18**:
thanks, this worked  for me

**Comment by [nunuwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/42390/nunuwin/) on 2019-07-03**:
I've the same error and I checked according to your advise for executing permission. In there I have no permission sign. How can I do to get permission?

**Comment by [Qusai](https://answers.ros.org/users/41724/qusai/) on 2019-07-21**:
thanks very much, the same problem with python file, it solved now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For python nodes, writing it as `type="file.py"` instead of just `type="file"` works for me.

---

Originally posted by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) with karma: 463 on 2019-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlessandroSaviolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/52672/alessandrosaviolo/) on 2020-03-19**:
Thanks! Solved my issue

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2020-03-19**:
Glad it helped :)